# Executing code to an other window through window.open()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I making this bot in JavaScript in the chrome console. And one of the lines in my script is `window.open('thewebsite','_self')` so it opens a different website in the same window. However I cant seem to execute code on that new website that I opened with window.open(). For example I want to do document.getElementById().click() however its not clicking on the new website I made.

For example:
If I was on google.com the script would open googleimages. But I want the next line of code for example typing in the search bar to happen on google images.

Answer (score 0):

`window.open` refreshes console, so you can't execute any code after.

You could try to get target url content and replace first page content, but you'll be blocked with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

What you're trying to achieve is indeed a macro. You should take a look at [iMacros](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imacros-for-chrome/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp) and see how they chain instructions from page to page.

Comment: thanks for your answer this will be very useful, can I implement javascript with imacros?